# trying to mount a LUKS file system attached to a VM in VMWare 16

Tags: luks

I had a power out while a VM was up and now I can't get back into it. I can get to initramfs or similar but that is drastically cut back. I've spun up another VM and pointed it at the VHD for the 'bad' OS but am unsure how to 'repair' it. The standard mount command doesn't seem to be what I need. This >> $ udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdd1 from Ask Ubuntu seems like it might work but I'm not there yet. I need someone who could do a chat or something and help me with some back and forth to see if I can recover this FS. I'm trying to head towards ckfs or similar to repair the journal but like I said. I'm stuck at the start and last time I used *nix was Unix System V so a while ago

Comment: Your profile doesnt have enough points to do a chat. However, I am happy to help elsewhere or if you post here

Comment: if the issue is `luks`, first you have to figure out how to resolve the luks container corruption. if you cant fix this, then the rest is not much useful

Comment: try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1032006/how-do-i-know-a-luks-header-is-corrupt